# Referencing a shared calendar

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, calendar

I tried to run the code from this question:
[Exporting Outlook calendar data to Excel file - Shared calendars and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974164/exporting-outlook-calendar-data-to-excel-file-shared-calendars-and-vba)

My code modification.

```
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myCalItems = olNS.CreateRecipient("theOtherUser")
myCalItems.Resolve
myCalItems.GetSharedDefaultFolder
```

I got error 13 Type mismatch. I've testing different combinations without result.

I tested this example too:
[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866418.aspx)

This info is useful but not enough: [http://www.snb-vba.eu/](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Outlook_external_en.html#L_10)

I need to export shared MS Outlook's calendars (with Exchange server) to MS Excel.

These calendars are shared to me and other people.

I run MS Office 2010 version.

Comment: Likely you reasonably declared myCalItems as items as the name would suggest. In your code myCalItems is something else. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What you using? Excel or Outlook -vba?

Comment: Hi! I'm using excel vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 13 in VBA means a type mismatch. See [Type mismatch (Error 13)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx) for more information.

You need to use the following code instead:

```
Sub ShowSharedFolder(OutlookApplication As Outlook.Application) 
   Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
   Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
   Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

   Set myNamespace = OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
   Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("theOtherUser") 
   myRecipient.Resolve 

   If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
     Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
     CalendarFolder.Display 
   End If 
End Sub
```