# VBscript outlook form creating meeting in specific calendar

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, outlook-2010

I've been working on this the past few days. My VBscript code works and will create a meeting in the default calendar in Outlook. The part I can't seem to figure out is how to have the meeting made in a custom calendar named "Test". This calendar is listed under "My Calendars". Any advice?

```
Sub commandbutton1_Click()                                  

If CommandButton1 = False Then

Const olFolderCalendar = 9
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olOutOfOffice = 3

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' bottom line original:  Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 

Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) '.Parent.Items("Test")
Set objApptItems = objCalendar.Items

objApptItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
objApptItems.Sort "[Start]"

Set objHoliday = objOutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 
                            'creating day off appointment
objHoliday.Subject = "Boxing Day"
objHoliday.Start = Item.UserProperties("DateText")
objHoliday.End = Item.UserProperties("EndDate")
objHoliday.AllDayEvent = True
objHoliday.ReminderSet = False
objHoliday.BusyStatus = olOutOfOffice
objHoliday.Save

                            'testing confirmation email
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(o)
    'Item.To
objMail.to = Item.To    'UserProperties("From")
objMail.Subject = "Confirmation: Requested Day(s) Off Approved"
objMail.Body = "Congratulations, your requested day(s) off have been Approved!"
objMail.Send

                            'closes email after hitting button
'For i = objOutlook.Inspectors.count To 1 Step -1
'        objOutlook.Inspectors.Item(i).Close True
'    Next

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is that folder physically located? Is it in another mailbox? A subfolder of the Calendar folder?

Comment: It is under the default 'My Calendars' so I believe it would be a subfolder. Ultimately, the calendar this code will be adding meetings to is locating under 'Shared Folders' but for testing purposes I made a calendar under 'My Calendars' named "Test".

Comment: And just in case I'm not being clear I have an example of what I'm trying to do but I need it in VBscript. The following is in VBA:  Set objCalendar = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Test") and works.

Comment: I have done a rollback to the question to get it back to mentioning VBScript in the title and in the tags.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm not quite sure why that other guy was looking to change the title to VBA.

Comment: I think they saw the VBA-ish code, and the [vba] and [outlook-vba] tags, and didn't realise that you were using VBScript to invoke the Outlook Application object and then access properties/methods of that object in a VBA-ish way.  Weren't you able to "reject" the suggested edit?  (I did so in the review queue, but two other people accepted it anyway.)  (P.S.  I only noticed it really was [vbscript] because I looked through your previous questions. It may have been better to emphasise that a bit in the current question - it's only the title / tag / invoking of the Application that mentions it.)

Comment: Yeah good point. I'll take that advice and add it in there to avoid anymore confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items are added to non-default calendars.

```
Sub Add_To_NonDefault_Folder()

    Dim objNameSpace As NameSpace
    Dim objCalendar As Folder
    Dim objHoliday As AppointmentItem

    Set objNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objCalendar = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Test")

    Set objApptItems = objCalendar.items
    Set objHoliday = objCalendar.items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    objHoliday.Subject = "Appt test"
    objHoliday.SAVE

End Sub
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for longer than you'd believe. Works perfectly!

Comment: Niton, can I ask one last thing of you? How would I change the code if the calendar "Test" was located in the 'Shared Calendars' column?

Comment: A new question would normally require a separate question post but I am guessing it would be a duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395994/referencing-a-shared-calendar